# How to get all data in one column of database codeigniter?

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I want to get all data in one column of the database (primary key) so that before I insert my data that is going to be inserted, I can check if its going to be duplicate or not.

Comment: You can simply run a query to check if primary key already exists. It's simple and easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

Model:

```
public function getKeys() {
    $this->db->select("key");
    $this->db->from("database");
    $result = $this->db->get();
    return $result->result();
}
```

Controller:

```
public function Controler() {
    $values = $this->MODEL_NAME->getKeys();
    foreach ($values as $value) {
        $array[] = $value->key;
    }
    # Compare new item to the current array
    if (!(in_array($NEWITEM, $array))) {
        # Insert
    } else {
        # Error catching
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At insert time get all data from table.and then use condition on a particular field by which you want to check this data is already exist or not: